# Does time taken by an SQL query to give the result depend on total number of rows in the table or on the final number of rows which is the result?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose there are 10 rows in a table named TABLE1 and there are a million rows in another table in TABLE2 and if I fire a query on these two table like these:

```
Select * from TABLE1 where some_column = 'some_value';
```

and

```
Select * from TABLE2 where some_column = 'some_value';
```

I know that in both cases I will get only 2 rows which satisfy the where clause, then how much would be the difference in time to get the result. I don't want to get any exact answer in figures. I just want to know that will both queries take the same time as the final result is only 2 rows that are satisfying the conditions or does the time taken depend on the total number of rows present in the table.

Comment: It depends. Really; what if the 10 million row table is really well indexed, and those results are in some form of database results cache? That means that it is conceivable that there are situations where you may receive the 2 rows from the 10m row table first, regardless of apparent difficulty. What if the table with 10 rows is actually the result of a complex, non-materialized view? There are *so* many factors that effect sql queries. Data amount is only one of them.

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to know that will both queries take the same time

The generic advice for such questions is: **do benchmarking**.

- Create a test database which contains the amount of data you expect later in the production system (you can easily do this with a simple PL/SQL script or with any other programming environment which supports database connectivity).
- Then, create a small application (ideally in the same programming environment where you will later execute the query) which executes the query (ideally multiple times) and measure the time it takes. Based on the result, you can take further actions.

In your specific case, it largely depends on whether there is an index on the `some_column` column. Without the index, the database needs to do a **full table scan** which means a linear search through all rows. If there is an index on the column, the queries should not take much different times.

If in doubt whether a full table scan is done or an index can be used for the query, you can create an [execution plan](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/ex_plan.htm) for your SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on how the tables are indexed. If there's an index on some_column, the time taken will be roughly the same for both queries (perhaps a little slower for table2, as the index for table1 will most likely reside in memory due to the smaller size).

If the tables are not indexed, the time taken for query 2 could be considerably larger, as the query processor would have to scan the entire 1.000.000 rows to find the rows that satisfy your WHERE-clause.

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, the speed by that your query runs is dependend on the index, that is used.
In most (trivial) cases you will have a primary key set up on your table wich leads to the simplest case of indexing, each row of your table has a unique number then by wich it can be compared and THAT is what takes up the time. In that case the time taken is dependend on the number of rows in your table, but that can vary greatly when you have different types of indexes on your table (yes there can be more than one ;))

further reading on [indexes](http://use-the-index-luke.com/welcome)

Answer (score 0):

As it has been advised, do benchmarking. A simple one - 2 tables with 10 and 300k rows - shows us that there's no huge difference (2 vs 4 database blocks read by query) in case your condition is highly selective.

```
15:22:14 HR@sandbox> ed
Wrote file S:\spool\sandbox\BUFFER_HR_42.sql

  1  create table table1 as
  2  select decode(rownum, 5, 6, 10, 6, mod(rownum, 5)) as value from dual
  3* connect by rownum <= 10
15:22:26 HR@sandbox> /

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.16
15:23:52 HR@sandbox> ed
Wrote file S:\spool\sandbox\BUFFER_HR_42.sql

  1   create table table2 as
  2   select decode(rownum, 1e3, 6, 5e4, 6, mod(rownum, 5)) as value from dual
  3*  connect by rownum <= 3e5
15:23:59 HR@sandbox> /

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:03.10
15:24:03 HR@sandbox> create index ix_t2_val on table2(value);

Index created.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.11
15:24:12 HR@sandbox> create index ix_t1_val on table1(value);

Index created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.05
15:24:16 HR@sandbox> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('hr','table1');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.93
15:25:14 HR@sandbox> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('hr','table2');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.19
15:25:18 HR@sandbox> select /*+index(table1 ix_t1_val)*/ * from table1 where value = 6;

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1719610244

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |           |     2 |     6 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| IX_T1_VAL |     2 |     6 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("VALUE"=6)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          2  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        369  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        363  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          2  rows processed

15:25:34 HR@sandbox> select /*+index(table1 ix_t2_val)*/ * from table2 where value = 6;

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4026617716

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |           | 50000 |   146K|    99   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| IX_T2_VAL | 50000 |   146K|    99   (0)| 00:00:02 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("VALUE"=6)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          4  consistent gets
          1  physical reads
          0  redo size
        369  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        363  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          2  rows processed
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the other answers talk about indexes as affecting query performance. While this is the big one, it's not just indexing which can affect the length of time taken by a query.

Five other cases, in the absence of all indexes:

1. Partitioned table: If one table is partitioned on `some_column` then Oracle can potentially scan just the single partition instead of the entire table. This is called *partition pruning* -- Oracle eliminates the partitions that it knows won't contain any data required in the query. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c12parti.htm#429785
2. Parallel full table scan: If you have parallel query enabled, Oracle can dynamically break the table into granules and parallel processes can scan each one for the value you're looking for. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96524/c20paral.htm#6346
3. Location of data on physical disks: different physical storage systems have different performance characteristics. A DBA can move certain *historical data* tables onto relatively slow, cheap storage while other tables are explicitly moved to relatively expensive, fast storage.
4. Oracle caching: a table's data can already be in memory, either automatically by Oracle or pinned manually. This will certainly affect performance.
5. Table "width". A wide table (one containing many columns) will be slower to scan than a narrow table containing fewer columns.

Comment: could you elaborate case #5?

Comment: Quite simply, if a table has eg 100 columns each containing say 10 bytes of data, then each row will occupy approx 1kb. Compare this to a table with eg 10 columns each containing say 10 bytes of data, then you can fit 10 rows in the same 1kb. Consequently a full table scan will be approximately 10 times slower for the larger table -- again with my proviso of the absence of all indexes.